# Cannot access click event's path in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've a little trouble with AngularJS, I have an app, for which a small controller and a few directives, I have to mention that the controller is only responsible for the search bar I made, so its not attached to the body tag.

Basically what I want to do, is determining whether the user clicked away from a drop-down at the search bar.

My current snippet:

```
$window.onclick = function(event) {
    console.log(event);
}
```

What I get is a nice `MouseEvent` object, with a path key, which I basically want to access since it'd be very easy:

```
if(event.path.indexOf('div#dropdown') {
    //the user didnt click away
}
```

But what I get is a huge window object when I type:

```
$window.onclick = function(event) {
    console.log(event.path);
}
```

I tried a few things but it seems nobody has this issue or whatsoever.

Comment: Shouldn't you be checking `event.target`? (This will be the actual clicked elem)

Comment: yes it can be done that way, but having this event.path, which really contains every element you clicked across, would make things easier, its only 1 line that way, cleaner, and nicer